# How to use VHDL to shift 2D array?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I first defined a binary array

```
type matrix_5x5_stdv is array ( Order - 1 downto 0, Order - 1 downto 0 ) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) ;
signal matrix_5x5_Img          : matrix_5x5_stdv ;
```

I want to shift the data in the first row of the array at each cycle as follow

```
process ( reset_n , sys_clk_125 )
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            matrix_5x5_Img <=  (others=>(others=>(others=>'0'))); 
        elsif rising_edge ( sys_clk_125 ) then          
            matrix_5x5_Img (0,4 downto 0) <= matrix_5x5_Img (0,3 downto 1),data  ;
        end if;
end process;
```

Vivado reported the following error

```
[Synth 8-2680] sliced name is allowed only on single-dimensional arrays
```

How to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're only moving data on the second (horizontal) axis in matrix_5x5_Img you could make matrix_5x5_stdv an array of arrays with elements of std_logic_vector, allowing slice names:

```vhdl
    constant Order: natural := 5;  -- an integer subtype
    type matrix_5_stdv is array (Order - 1 downto 0) of 
         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    type matrix_5x5_stdv is array (Order - 1 downto 0) of matrix_5_stdv;
    
    -- type matrix_5x5_stdv is array ( Order - 1 downto 0, Order - 1 downto 0 ) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    
    signal matrix_5x5_Img: matrix_5x5_stdv;
```

In the following example there is a to_string function added for VHDL standard revisions earlier that -2008 to display what happens to the matrix values for matrix_5x5_Img(0) and a init_val_matrix function to provide distinct values for all the matrix elements at reset. There's also an added MONITOR_5X5_IMG process to display the contents of the matrix when it's value changes by event.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shift_2d_array is
    port (
        sys_clk_125:    in  std_logic;
        reset_n:        in  std_logic;
        data:           in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of shift_2d_array is
    constant Order: natural := 5;  -- an integer subtype
    type matrix_5_stdv is array (Order - 1 downto 0) of 
         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    type matrix_5x5_stdv is array (Order - 1 downto 0) of matrix_5_stdv;
    
    -- type matrix_5x5_stdv is array ( Order - 1 downto 0, Order - 1 downto 0 ) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    
    signal matrix_5x5_Img: matrix_5x5_stdv;
    
    function init_val_matrix return matrix_5x5_stdv is
        variable retval:  matrix_5x5_stdv;
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        for i in retval'range loop
            for j in retval(0)'range loop
                retval(i)(j) := std_logic_vector
                                    ( to_unsigned(i, 4) & to_unsigned(j, 4) );
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return retval;
    end function;
    
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
    
begin

    process (reset_n, sys_clk_125)
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            -- matrix_5x5_Img <=  (others => (others => (others => '0'))); 
            matrix_5x5_Img <= init_val_matrix;
        elsif rising_edge (sys_clk_125) then          
            -- matrix_5x5_Img (0,4 downto 0) <= matrix_5x5_Img (0,3 downto 1),data;
            -- Vivado [Synth 8-2680] sliced name is allowed only on single-dimensional arrays
            matrix_5x5_Img(0)(4 downto 0) <= 
                 matrix_5x5_Img(0)(3 downto 0) &  data;
        end if;
    end process;
    
MONITOR_5X5_IMG:
    process (matrix_5x5_Img)
        use std.textio.all;
        variable lbuf:   line;
    begin
        write(lbuf, LF & integer'image(now/ns) & " ns" & LF & HT);
        write(lbuf, " (4)" & HT & "  (3)" & HT & "   (2)" & HT & "    (1)"  & HT 
                  & "     (0)" & LF & HT);
        for i in matrix_5x5_Img'range loop
            -- write(lbuf, HT & '(' & integer'image(i) & ')' & LF & HT);
            for j in matrix_5x5_Img(0)'range loop
                write(lbuf, to_string(matrix_5x5_Img(i)(j)) & ' ');
            end loop;
            write(lbuf, '(' & integer'image(i) & ')' & LF);
            if i > 0 then
                write(lbuf, HT);
            end if;
        end loop;
        writeline(output,lbuf);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The original process is modified to use separate indexes which allows slicing:

```vhdl
    process (reset_n, sys_clk_125)
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            -- matrix_5x5_Img <=  (others => (others => (others => '0'))); 
            matrix_5x5_Img <= init_val_matrix;
        elsif rising_edge (sys_clk_125) then          
            -- matrix_5x5_Img (0,4 downto 0) <= matrix_5x5_Img (0,3 downto 1),data;
            -- Vivado [Synth 8-2680] sliced name is allowed only on single-dimensional arrays
            matrix_5x5_Img(0)(4 downto 0) <= 
                 matrix_5x5_Img(0)(3 downto 0) &  data;
        end if;
    end process;
```

To enable demonstration, a testbench:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shift_2d_array_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of shift_2d_array_tb is
    signal stop:    boolean;  -- default FALSE
    signal sys_clk_125: std_logic := '0';
    signal reset_n:     std_logic := '1';
    signal data:        std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal index:       integer range 0 to 4;  -- default 0
    type slv_array is array (0 to 4) of std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0);
    constant input: slv_array := (x"FE", x"ED", x"FA", x"CE", x"DE" );
begin
DUT:
    entity work.shift_2d_array
        port map (
            sys_clk_125 => sys_clk_125,
            reset_n => reset_n,
            data => data
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 4 ns;
        sys_clk_125 <= not sys_clk_125;
        if stop then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
RESET:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset_n <= '0';
        wait for 13 ns;
        reset_n <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
INDEXED:
    process (reset_n, sys_clk_125)
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            index <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(sys_clk_125) then
            if index < 4 then
                index <= index + 1;
            else
                stop <= true;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    data <= input(index);  -- AVOID having a data register
    
end architecture;
```

And this produced:

```
/usr/local/bin/ghdl -r  shift_2d_array_tb --wave=shift_2d_array_tb.ghw

0 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU (4)
    UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU (3)
    UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU (2)
    UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU (1)
    UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU (0)


1 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    00000100 00000011 00000010 00000001 00000000 (0)


20 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    00000011 00000010 00000001 00000000 11111110 (0)


28 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    00000010 00000001 00000000 11111110 11101101 (0)


36 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    00000001 00000000 11111110 11101101 11111010 (0)


44 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    00000000 11111110 11101101 11111010 11001110 (0)


52 ns
     (4)      (3)      (2)      (1)      (0)
    01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001 01000000 (4)
    00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000 (3)
    00100100 00100011 00100010 00100001 00100000 (2)
    00010100 00010011 00010010 00010001 00010000 (1)
    11111110 11101101 11111010 11001110 11011110 (0)

/usr/local/bin/gtkwave shift_2d_array_tb.gtkw &
%:
GTKWave Analyzer v3.4.0 (w)1999-2022 BSI

[0] start time.
[56000000] end time.
```

[image: shift_2d_array_tb.jpg]

IF you need an actual multidimensional array type you might want functions or procedures to manipulate matrix values on both axis.

Patrick's answer to [Synthesizable multidimensional arrays in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30655569) has links to his [PoC.vectors](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl) package that can serve as inspiration (perhaps without immersing yourself in the entirety of PoC).

As you might gather, the error message has been the subject of questions before, as in Patrick's answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that Order is 5 in your example, as you use `matrix_5x5_Img (0,4 downto 0)`. So you want to shift the complete first row. Then a solution is:

```
process ( reset_n , sys_clk_125 )
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            matrix_5x5_Img <=  (others=>(others=>(others=>'0')));
        elsif rising_edge ( sys_clk_125 ) then
            matrix_5x5_Img(0, 0) <= data;
            for col in 1 to Order-1 loop
                matrix_5x5_Img (0, col) <= matrix_5x5_Img (0,col-1);
            end loop;
        end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop statement as below:

```
process ( reset_n , sys_clk_125 )
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            matrix_5x5_Img <=  (others=>(others=>(others=>'0'))); 
        elsif rising_edge ( sys_clk_125 ) then          
            g_shift : for ii in 0 to 3 loop
                matrix_5x5_Img (0,0) <= data  ;
                matrix_5x5_Img (0,ii+1) <= matrix_5x5_Img (0,ii);
            end loop g_shift;
        end if;
end process;
```